I want to convert below stored function to MySQL stored function with returns datatype more than one datatype
I want a stored function in MySQL format with returns more than one datatypes
CREATE FUNCTION "neura_iitm_prod".patient_details_fun(from_date date,to_date date)

RETURNING varchar(20),varchar(150),varchar(30),date;
DEFINE v_patient_id varchar(20);
DEFINE V_patient_name varchar(150);
DEFINE v_gender_desc varchar(30);
DEFINE v_generated_date date;
FOREACH CUR FOR
 SELECT pdt.patient_id,pdt.first_name||''||pdt.last_name as patient_name,
       (select mgt.gender_desc 
        from master_gender_tbl mgt 
        where pdt.gender_id = mgt.gender_id) as v_gender_desc , 
        pdt.generated_date
 INTO
        v_patient_id,V_patient_name,v_gender_desc,v_generated_date
 FROM
        patient_details_tbl pdt
 WHERE
        pdt.generated_date  between from_date and to_date
RETURN v_patient_id,V_patient_name,v_gender_desc,v_generated_date WITH RESUME ;
END FOREACH;

END FUNCTION


you should add more details, and please edit your code as code blog

'I want a stored function in MySQL format with returns more than one datatypes' - not possible in mysql , also there are other things you need to consider , mysql does not have foreach cur and || is s synonymn for OR. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/create-procedure.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/cursors.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/logical-operators.html In addition mysql does not have table value functions and cannot return a result set.

please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Which DBMS does the SQL code shown run on? Informix? Provide a code sample which demonstrates how is this function used.

It sounds like you actually need a stored procedure, not function. If the procedure performs a SELECT that doesn't save into variables, calling the procedure is like executing that query, and you can process the result set in the caller.
